# GLFW window not showing anything

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glfw

My code is as follows, mostly following http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials.

```cpp
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);

    glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, 1024, 0, 768, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    do {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPointSize(20);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        }
        glEnd();

        glLineWidth(5);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        }
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    } while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Only a white window shows and no lines or points are drawn. What's more, when I follow the tutorial on http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials and try to set the line width of the triangles I also failed. Thanks.

Comment: Since there's `<vector>` included, that can hardly be related to [tag:c]. Removed.

Comment: You are using a Core profile OpenGL Context (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`). So you can't use the legacy OpenGL API (`glBegin`, `glEnd` ...). You have to use "modern" OpenGL. See [Why is OpenGL GLFW Rendering shapes not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74169281/why-is-opengl-glfw-rendering-shapes-not-working)